# SSL-Redirect annotation for ALB ingress resource

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to add an ssl-redirect annotation in my ingress resource to redirect traffic from http to https. I am using AWS ALB Controller v2.4.2

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

To enable http->https redirects on an ingress with AWS ALBs, you just need to set the following [annotation](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/ingress/annotations/#ssl-redirect) on the ingress object

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443'
```